# HowTo Publish ASP.NET Project on Web to work as it does locally?

Tags: .net, asp.net, database

I just followed a tutorial that created a database and two .aspx web forms.. And it runs perfectly when I view the asp pages in my browser.  But when I FTP'd the files:

Default.aspx
AddEntry.aspx
And my entire App_Data folder (with the .mdf and .ldf files)

It doesn't view at the URL.  For example.. When I go to http://www.mysite.com/project/Default.aspx it doesn't load my web form... It just displays raw text saying....

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
```

Etc.  How do I properly publish it so it works like when I view it locally?

EDIT:

Still haven't found expert settings -- Also...

I tried this on a web server that I'm pretty certain has ASP installed and it gives me an error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application

Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".
```

Whyy????

Comment: Also, I am using Visual Web Developer 2008 Express edition

Comment: Do you have ASP.NET installed on your machine and IIS/whichever webserver you are using? Does it run fine in debug mode?

Comment: Sounds like ASP.NET is not installed.

Comment: The folder that you are publishing to needs to be setup as a Virtual Folder under IIS running on that server. Did you do this?

Comment: Raze: I haven't installed ASP.NET on my web server myself. (Godaddy) But I do see that ASP is supported with my hosting package.  And yes, it runs fine in debugging mode.

Comment: You need to enable remote debugging in web.config - that's why you get the second message and I hazard a guess at your main error is to do with the database connection

Answer (score 1):

You need to properly configure the site on the server.

The easiest way to do that is to use the Publish Website command form the Build menu. I think you need to select Expert Settings in WebDeveloper first.

And the Server needs to be configured for ASP.NET, just install the right version of .NET on the server, and maybe fix-up by running ASPNET_REGIIS.exe

Comment: I don't have the Publish Website command on my Build menu. I am using Visual Web Developer 2008 Express.. Maybe that is only an option in Visual Studio?

Comment: No, that simply means that you created a "Web Site Project" and not a "Web Application Project". Use google to find out what the differences are. In a "Web Site Project" is another menu point that is called "Copy Site"

Comment: I only have WebDev 2010 here. The Build menu shows "Publish WebApplication1". But did you find the Expert settings?

Comment: @citronas: That is indeed another possibility. In a 'Web __Site__ project' you have a WebSite item in the main menu. With the Copy item.